# How to delete records from multiple tables

Tags: go

I'm creating a script that's meant to pass in an argument into a MySQL query, and then execute that MySQL query to delete multiple records from multiple tables.

Right now I am running into an issue where I need to create multiple files for each separate table.
Is there a way I can execute every MySQL query within one file instead of creating multiple files for each query?

Here's the code I've created:

```
import (
"fmt"
"database/sql"
"os"
)

func DeleteTables() {
   fmt.Println("Test for MySQL")

   db, _ := sql.Open(
       "mysql", "user:password@(localhost:port)/db")

   args := os.Args
   if len(args) < 2 {
       fmt.Println("Supply a ID")
       os.Exit(1)
   }
   id := os.Args[1]
   fmt.Println(id)

   delete, err := db.Query("DELETE * FROM table1 WHERE id = ?;", id)

   if err != nil {
       panic(err.Error())
   }
   defer delete.Close()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "...create multiple files for each separate table?"

Comment: What I mean is:  I don't want to create a new .go file for each table that needs to be executed. I'd like all the queries to execute from one .go file. So: DELETE from table1 where id  = ? and in the same .go file, DELETE from table2 where id = ?, ect.

Comment: I want to pass multiple DELETE statements at once, in one Go File.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want to pass arguments to MySQL query for deletion, but in multiple tables. So why don't you take table name also as in input and write one switch case statement based on table name to fetch the query as per table name and then apply your query argument

Comment: Use multiple `db.Query` calls, one for each table. Better, use a for-loop, and do not use defer, instead close the statement after error check.

Comment: are these tables related like table2 has foreign key of table1 ? something like that? then you can use mysql delete query with join, it will save you one db call
DELETE T1, T2
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.key = T2.key
WHERE condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for-loop to submit DELETE statements for multiple tables. If the table names are fixed, use something like below:

```
for _,table:= range []string{"table1","table2","table3"} {
   _, err := db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("DELETE * FROM %s WHERE id = ?;",table), id)
   if err != nil {
       panic(err.Error())
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is almost perfect, except the other tables do link to eachotherm however the linking columns are not named the same. Eg. table1 has a column of id, but table2 has the FK link of table_1_id

Comment: Use the delete join statement, as mentioned in the comments.